# Is using the Cache in WebMatrix user-specific or application-specific?

Tags: c#, caching, webmatrix, asp.net-webpages

If I were to use `AppState` variables as opposed to `Session` variables, I would not be storing data user-specifically. That is, if one user changes an `AppState` variable, it remains changed for all users on a site (it is application specific).

My question is, if I store values using the cache to transfer data between asp.net web-pages, is it user-specific or application specific?  I always assumed it would be user-specific, however I read this:

> The Cache is primarily intended to be used to improve performance of
>   web pages, in that you can add any arbitrary object to it and retrieve
>   it at will. Cache items are stored in memory on the server, and can be
>   considered as special global variables.

(This is from:  http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/192/Transferring-Data-Between-ASP.NET-Web-Pages)

Knowing that the actual values are stored on the server, I began to wonder if the reference to these values are stored client side (like with Session variables) or if they are 100% stored server-side.

I would test this myself, but my work environment isn't really suitable for me to 'hop' on different machines very easily.

Comment: Presumably 100% serverside as there is no usercomponent.. (comparable to the old-school application object and not the session object)

Comment: @AzardVark71 Thank you for the reply. I am beginning to feel very glad that I asked this question before attempting to transfer my 21 string variables along with my 9 12-index arrays across asp.net web-pages (and all for the sake of remembering form data through an OAuth request :S).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Cache is not user specific. It is similar to `AppState`, except that you can set expiration times on items in the Cache, and establish dependencies e.g. on a file or a SQL Server database (although you can't do that last part through the `System.Web.Helpers.WebCache` helper).

Comment: Acutally, you can set the expiration time on items in the Cache through the WebCache helper. When you set the value (using WebCache.Set method : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.webcache.set(v=vs.111).aspx) the third optional paramater is minutesToCache (default being 20 minutes)

Comment: @AardVark71 Thanks - dunno how I managed to overlook that. I even covered it in my book. Amended my answer for accuracy.